# Stripe Framework in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe SDK and everything has been going great. I followed the instructions and did the Static Framework install via https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

The issue I am having, is only when I close XCode, then re-open, it's telling me "Module Stripe not found" under the line in my delegate:

```
@import Stripe;
```

Only when I delete the framework, then re-ad, does it work again. This I assume is an XCode bug but it's quite annoying to have to re-add the framework everytime I close XCode.

I have tried importing other ways as well with no luck like:

```
#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?